# How to run grunt with node's --no-deprecation?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

I want to disable the warning because I get lof of errors and the app, crash and I can't event test it. I read that `--no-deprecation` will silent that warning but how can I run grunt with it. I've try to put into grunt main file and call `grunt --no-deprecation taks`. But don't work. I've still got the warning and grunt crashed.

Comment: Just a guess, but something like `node --no-deprecation /usr/local/bin/grunt` (change the path for whatever the path is on your machine) might work?

Comment: @AndreasHultgren I still have the warning and the app crash, Maybe grunt run node again, I don't know much about grunt.